# What are some applications of loops in real life?

Tags: graph-theory

I am aware of the real world applications of simple graphs and graphs with multiple edges but how are loops used? For example, a few computers linked to each other would be an example of simple graphs or graphs with multiple edges, where multiple edges can represent links with different speeds of communication. But where would one see loops in real life?

Comment: You're not talking about cycles, right?  You're talking about self-loops?

Comment: I mean I don't know if you would consider this a "real world example" or not, but self loops are important in automata for checking things like [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times).

Comment: Yes @Jared I mean self loops. So far I have seen examples of loops in algorithms, but I feel even then they should be considered as cycles rather than self loops. For example, a 'for loop' would contain the 'for' statement followed by a few lines of code. Considering each line of code as a node, we essentially have a cycle.

Comment: ...well, a self loop _is_ a cycle--there's no getting around that.  So for instance if the regular expression is $x^*y$, then the automata will cycle on the transition $x$.  I.e. if you first see an x, then if you see another x, you go back to where you started.

Comment: they can frequently be used to represent idempotent operations which return the system to same state for example multiplication by 1

Comment: I'll present another example: let's say you are trying to mathematically model the operations of an elevator.  What happens if I press floor 5 and then some one comes in and presses the button for floor 5 again?  This is a self loop--it puts us into the same state: the elevator is still going to stop at floor 5.

Comment: True, a self loop is a cycle, but every cycle is not a self loop. Wouldn't you consider the "if you first see an x" as one node and "then if you see another x" as another node? We already have 2 nodes, so in my opinion there isn't a self loop here..? But whatever it may be, I'm hoping for a more concrete real world application than algorithms. D.B. West in his book _Introduction to Graph Theory_ says, _"In many important applications. loops and multiple edges do not arise, and we restrict our attention to simple graphs"_. I hope we find an unimportant application at least.

Comment: Is it true that every cycle isn't a self loop?  I would argue that you can abstract a cycle to a self loop.  If a sequence of events leads you to the same state, then you can abstract that sequence of events into a self loop.  Perhaps that's a convolution though.

Comment: imagine the context of http://neo4j.com/books/graph-databases/; a backbone for social networking. Now try and imagine what a loop does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can produce a broad class of examples via the graphs associated to *Markov chains*, which have applications in chemistry, queueing theory, genetics, board games, and more.

Consider a system with $n$ states, denoted $s^b$, that evolves in discrete steps: At each (discrete) time step, the system may change the state, say; if it is in state $s^b$, let $p^a{}_b$ be the probability that (at a particular time step) it changes to state $s^a$. In particular, in a Markov chain these probabilities are *state functions* they depend only on the current state, not on the previous history of the system, so the probabilities $p^a{}_b$ are the same for each time step; in turn, these probabilities together define the Markov chain completely.

A particularly simple example comes from a Poisson process: Suppose one buys a new pet crocodile, which has two states, $s_{\text{alive}}$ and $s_{\text{dead}}$. Each day it is alive, the crocodile has some small ($\epsilon \ll 1$) probability of dying, and a dead crocodile stays dead. Then, the probabilities are $p^{\text{alive}}{}_{\text{alive}} = 1 - \epsilon$, $p^{\text{dead}}{}_{\text{alive}} = \epsilon$, $p^{\text{alive}}{}_{\text{dead}} = 0$, and (sadly) $p^{\text{dead}}{}_{\text{dead}} = 1$.

We often represent a Markov chain as a matrix with $(a, b)$ entry $p^a{}_b$ (each row must, by definition of probability, sum to $1$), which facilitates easy computation of many interesting properties related to the underlying system. But we can also represent a Markov chain as a labeled digraph with no multiple edges, whose vertices are the states of the system, and whose (directed) edges represent transitions from one state to another; the edge from $s^b$ to $s^a$ is labeled with the probability $p^a{}_b$. (Sometimes one omits edges corresponding to transitions with probability zero, which makes it easier, e.g., to find *sinks*, that is, states from which the system does not escape.) In this case, a (directed) loop encodes the transition from a state to itself, like the crocodile remaining alive (or remaining dead).

**Edit** Wikipedia has a short article dedicated to [examples of Markov chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_Markov_chains), including some digraphs of the sort mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't accept regular expression checking as a "real world example" (even though these are of utmost importance to computer programming), but it absolutely involves self-loops, just as the following example I gave: $x^*y$:

[image]

I'm guessing our difference here is in using graphs to describe [finite state machines](https://www.google.com/search?q=elevator+finite+state+machine&espv=2&biw=1855&bih=969&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=LHdVVZghxdigBMyEgNgH&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg&dpr=1#)--which you don't (perhaps) see as a "real world example".